# WooCommerce Add to Cart not showing for Guest

Tags: checkout, woocommerce

If you go to this page and try to make a selection, you can see that the add to cart button isn't showing up. http://lihitmenlacrosse.com/product/li-hitmen-t-shirt-2/

If you are logged in and make a selection the add to cart button will show. I've searched and can't seem to figure out why this is happening. All I've seen is instances where the button hasn't shown up at all, but in my case it does show up when I'm logged in but not when I am not logged in and am browsing as a guest.

Under Templates it says:
Template Overrides:     No core overrides present in theme.

Also I am using the U-Design theme if that makes any difference.

I really appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: So if you did not changed anything at all consolidate the template developers or check the woocommerce documentation. There is nothing we could help you with since this is a plattform for problems regrading programming.

Comment: I know that part of it is hidden via CSS and I've seen similar woocommerce issues addressed here which is why I posted my question.